# How can I show that if $f\in L^p(a, b)$ then $\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\int_{a}^b |f(x+t)-f(x)|^p\ dx=0$..

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

can anyone help me show that if $f\in L^p(a, b)$ then $$ \lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\int_{a}^b|f(x+t)-f(x)|^p\ dx=0.$$ Thanks, any help will be useful..

Comment: What have you done so far? You can show the continuity of $\tau_h$ def. by
$$\tau_h f(x) := f(x+h)$$
As an Operator on $L^p$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\tau_h f(x) = f(x+h)$ denote the translation operator. If $f$ is a continuous compactly supported function, the desired assertion follows from the dominated convergence theorem. Otherwise, there exists a continuous compactly supported function $g$ with $\|f - g \|_p < \epsilon$. The translation invariance of Lebesgue measure implies
$$\|f - \tau_h f\|_p \le \|f - g \|_p + \|g - \tau_h g \|_p + \|\tau_h g - \tau_h f \|_p$$
$$\le 2\|f - g \|_p + \|g - \tau_h g \|_p \le 3\epsilon$$
for small enough $h$.