# $f(x+1/n)\to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm working on a problem in my past Qual.

"Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that $f(x+1/n)\to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$."

We have $\int |f(x+1/n)|=\int |f|<\infty$. The sequence is uniformly dominated by $f\in L^1$. So by the diagram in https://www.johndcook.com/blog/modes_of_convergence/, it suffices to prove that $f(x+1/n)\to f$ almost everywhere or in measure.

However, both involve evaluating $|f(x+1/n)- f(x)|$. I don't think this is possible since $f$ is not continuous. This is where I'm out of approaches.

Comment: The sequence is neither almost everywhere convergent nor dominated by $f$.

Comment: why not dominated? where is my argument flawed?

Comment: Dominated by $f$ means $|f(x+\frac 1 n)| \leq |f(x)|$ for almost all $x$.

Comment: okay i see. So what I'm saying here is that the sequence are all in $L^1$. ANd that's it. It means that I don't have any approach

Comment: This requires some theorems in measure theory. Do you now that continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^{1}$?

Comment: i do, but i never use it in a problem. I guess this problem is harder than i thought

Comment: This result is true in any $L^p$ with $1 \leq p < \infty$. It follows by the the fact that the translation is continuous in the $L^p$ norm (see Folland, Real Analysis, Second edition, Proposition 8.5). The proof involves the density of continuous functions with compact support in $L^p$, that @KaviRamaMurthy mentioned.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/488393/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/488393/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/842937/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose a continuous function $g$ with compact support such that $\int |f-g| <\epsilon /3$. Now $$\int |f(x+\frac   1 n)-f(x)| dx$$ $$\leq \int |f(x+\frac   1 n)-g(x+\frac 1 n)| dx$$ $$+\int |g(x+\frac   1 n)-g(x)| dx$$ $$+ \int|g(x)-f(x)| dx <2\epsilon /3+$$ $$\int |g(x+\frac   1 n)-g(x)| dx$$ To show that $\int |g(x+\frac   1 n)-g(x)| dx< \epsilon /3$ for $n$ sufficiently large use the following:

1) It is enough to integrate over a  compact interval $[a,b]$

2) $g$ is uniformly continuous

Can you now finish the proof?

Comment: i'll try to do it

Comment: I'd say since the support is where the values are nonzero, then we only need to integrate over that compact set. And continuous on a compact set means uniformly continuos. Is this correct? How do you reduce to just 1 interval?

Comment: @TC If $g$ is $0$ outside $[-N,N]$ then $g(x+\frac  1n)-g(x)$ is $0$ for all $n$ outside the interval $[-N-1,N+1]$. So we can take the integral over $[-N-1,N+1]$.

Comment: oh i see it's bounded. So just take a large interval